# passing parameters from powershell script to another

Tags: powershell-3.0

I've investigated this forum. But do not seem to understand it good enough to find my answer. I'm absolutely new at Powershell.

I've a situation that I've started a ps1-script and need to execute another ps1-script to start in the background with passing parameters from the first script to the second.

Something like this (script1.ps1):

```
$var1 = "p1 (string value)"
$var2 = "p2 (string value)"
$var3 = "p3 (string value)"
$var4 = 4 # numeric value

$counter = 1

while ($counter -le $var4)
{
    #call to script2.ps1 with passing the $var1 through $var4 as
    #parameters so that script2.ps1 executes as a background process
    #and works with the received parameters $var1 through $var4
    # ??
    $counter= $counter + 1
}

exit
########################################
```

I can't find 1 way to pass the parameters and start script2.ps1 in the background.

Really hoping that someone can help me.

THIA,
Wim

Comment: why don't you want to pass them as array and just process them one by one in the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will help you [About_Jobs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/about/about_Jobs)

Get-Help [Start-Job](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/start-job)

https://sqlblog.org/2011/01/29/powershell-start-job-scriptblock-sad-panda-face

Answer (score 1):

This did the trick for me.

```
$var1 = "p1 (string value)"
$var2 = "p2 (string value)"
$var3 = "p3 (string value)"
$var4 = 4 # numeric value

$counter = 1
while ($counter -le $var4)
{

    $Params = "-Param1 $var1 -Param2 $var2 -Param3 $var3"
    $Script = [scriptblock]::create("d:\temp\scriptname.ps1 $Params")
    Start-Job -ScriptBlock $Script

    $counter = $counter+1
}

exit
```